# Apache Beam python code for branching out pipelines

Tags: python-3.x, apache-beam

I am using Dataflow for loading a CSV file where each record depending on the first column value needs to be written to a particular bigquery table.

Explained in simple terms below:
Input file -

```
1,X1,Y1
2,X2,Y2
3,X3,Y3
```

Code Logic -

```
If col1 = 1 then write into table1
If col2 = 2 then write into table2
and so on so forth....
```

For that reason I was going through the Apache Beam documentation https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/design-your-pipeline/
but this shows JAVA code. I don't know JAVA and want to write it in Python. Can anyone please share the link to such documentation for Python code?

Answer (score 0):

The Beam programming guide contains instructions for both the Java and Python SDKs. https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/